# How do I fix my golang import cycle error

Tags: go

So I have made a basic go package that just gives you colored text in terminal, now i have confirgured the stuff, created go mod for the package,but when i run the file that is importing the package it gives me this error

```
import cycle not allowed
package main
        imports github.com/Rachit4/colora
        imports github.com/Rachit4/colora
```

my main.go file is

```golang
package main

import "github.com/Rachit4/colora"

func main() {
        red("test")
}
```

Comment: the problem is in the module you've written, look to see how it imports itself

Comment: your description of the problem is incomplete or inaccurate. Please edit with a reproducible example.

Comment: @mh-cbon your comment I would like to say BRUH!

Comment: in the end your answer contains the reproducible example that was needed in your original question so that you can get meaningful help. You might dislike, yet, doing those steps eliminate most questions, and if not, ensures other people can effictively help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

After a bit more clarification in the comments.

Your module is not initialised. Find the official Go tutorial [here](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started#call) and [here](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/create-module). I will show you in the answer as well a step-by-step.

You will first need to use `go mod init` inside the root directory of your project. I'm going to assume you are using Linux, but you can do the same commands in Windows.

Inside your terminal:

```
$ go mod init github.com/Rachit4/colora
```

Then secondly, for your main package to access your functions in the package colora, you will need to `export` them by changing them to capital letters.

My Project structure:

```
- colora (module github.com/Rachit4/colora)
  - go.mod
  - colora.go
  - test.go
  - test/
    - main.go
```

Please check my Go Playground for the code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/j80i_4LCeD6).

For example, calling the functions inside the same package:

`test.go`

```
package colora

func test() {
    red("I am red")
}
```

`test/main.go`

```
package main

import "github.com/Rachit4/colora"

func main() {
  red("i am red") // this won't work
}
```

Export the functions in your `colora.go` file by capatalising your methods.

`colora.go`

```
func Red(text string) {
    fmt.Println(string(colorRed), text)
}
```

Now it will be callable in `main.go` with

```
colora.Red()
```

I would suggest reading up on structuring your project, although Go has very loose guidelines on structuring a project - they do suggest keeping pakcages for instances in separate folders. If you want a bit more structure, you can check out [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) about project layouts in Go.

### Old answer

So if I understand you correctly, you have a go package ("github.com/Rachit4/colora") which you want to import in a new project? or is it still in the same project?

If you are importing it in a new project, did you perhaps by accident give the new project a module with the same name?

So e.g.

**Project 1:**

- github.com/Rachit4/colora/ (module in go.mod)

  - colora.go

**Project 2:**

- github.com/Rachit4/colora/ (module in go.mod)

  - main.go <-- import "github.com/Rachit4/colora"

Comment: No i just made a folder named test and a file named main.go, just to test that is it importing or not.

Comment: you can see the github repo for the package https://github.com/Rachit4/colora

Comment: @Inferus awesome! Please just mark the answer as correct when you get the chance :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a problem with the package you are trying to import. I would suggest reading [publishing go modules](https://blog.golang.org/publishing-go-modules) section from the docs. My hunch is go runtime is not recognizing it as a proper module (maybe try adding a go.mod in the colora package).